# Restrict the review queue restrictions for users

Tags: feature-request, documentation

[This edit of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/49488) finally got accepted. But since the approving user just has a few reputation points, while not even having ANY SCORE in the topic C and just even a score of 2 for C++, I don't feel like he had even any idea of the changes I did and why they improved the example by removing parts from it and extending other parts.

This time it went well (presuming my knowledge I injected into the example was appropriate), but this shows that the way reviews actually are working will result in random chances about good changes being rejected or bad ones getting approved.

And there needs to be a restriction about who is allowed to reject/approve and who isn't. If one isn't proficient in a specific tag, at least they should have some decent overall reputation.

Comment: Welcome to the downfalls of the current suggested edits system, which are many. Now with more rep :)